# Socketio send message to specific client in namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

server side:

```
io.of('/lobby').on('connection', function(client) {
    setInterval(function(){
        io.to(client.id).emit('message','test');
    },2000);
});
```

client side:

```
var ioLobby = io.connect('127.0.0.1:9001/lobby');
ioLobby.on('message',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

I'm trying to send a message to a specific client in socket.io version 1.2.1. I've verified that the socket joins the default room on the server side, but its not being triggered on the client side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compromised and ended up using

```
socket.emit()
```

The only downside in comparison is requiring a ref to the socket you're emitting to.

Answer (score 0):

The line io.to(client.id) will only work if that user has first joined a room with that same name. You need something like

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

and then you can call io.to

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event'):
```

Comment: All clients automatically join a room whose name is their client id upon connection.

Comment: It's possible that on your client side, you are calling the second line before ioLobby has finished setting up the connection